# List<T> в строку

Tags: c#, json, list

Есть класс для десериализации `json` строки

```
  public class RootObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string display_advertiser { get; set; }
        public object advertiser_id { get; set; }
    }
```

В коде программы я входную json-строку десериализую в него

```
  List<RootObject> root = new List<RootObject>();
  var item = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(str);
  root.Add(item)
```

Теперь я хочу пробежаться по элементам `root` и данные каждого экземпляра объединить в строку с разделителем `;`

```
for (int i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
{
    var data = string.Join(";",... а что писать тут?);
}
```

В общем не совсем понятно как преобразовать элемент массива в строку.

Comment: переопредели метод `ToString` у класса `RootObject`

Comment: Покажите пример списка элементов и текста, который должен из этого списка получиться.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string display_advertiser { get; set; }
        public object advertiser_id { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{id},{display_advertiser},{advertiser_id}";
        }
    }

    ...

    var data = string.Join(";", root);
```

Comment: Достаточно указать только список. `ToString()` для каждого элемента будет вызван автоматически.

Comment: поправил, точно, спасибо